# What is the favorite oblation to matha kaalratri?

Tags: durga, kali

I need to know which oblation maatha Kalratri likes much.

Comment: Do you mean oblation rather than obligation?

Comment: yes oblation. sorry for typo. I am following a guru.He is worshipping ma kalratri. without his permission. i started worship with her mantra. i could sense vibration when chanting. and i do yagya. i couldnt reach my guru to ask this question. that's why posted here. i just want to what oblation can give her in yagya. what she like?